# How to map two commands under one shortcut in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have written in my vim configuration file.

```
map <f2> :w<cr>:!D:\Python34\python %<cr>
```

When I press <kbd>F2</kbd>, the currently edited python file will be interpreted.
Now I want to set 65001 in command, then to execute the python file.

How to express two commands in a row in my map?

```
map <f2> :w<cr>:!chcp 65001 and D:\Python34\python %<cr>
```

Comment: Is `nnoremap <f2> :w <bar> !chcp 65001 && D:\Python32\python %<cr>` what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you just want execute two cmd commands in a row.
Use & between cmd commands.
So it becomes,

```
map <f2> :w<cr>:!chcp 65001 & D:\Python34\python %<cr>
```